# How to create an irregular shape for images using css?

Tags: css, polygon, css-shapes, clip-path

Is it possible to create an irregular shape for images with CSS like in this [url](https://ruinedking.com/en-us/)? As a starter point I made this but I do not manage to make more irregularities appear on each side of the image, as in the example url mentioned above:

```
.div img {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 16% 2%, 39% 0%, 83% 4%, 100% 0%, 100% 24%, 98% 48%, 100% 75%, 100% 100%, 75% 97%, 45% 100%, 1% 100%, 7% 81%, 0% 56%);
}
```

Basically, I want it to look
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h81W8.png)

Comment: Yes you can clip things, but I'm not sure what your actual question is - are you seeing a problem with the clip-path you have used? Please describe what you want to see versus what you actually see and make a snippet so we can see your structure. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with this.

Comment: @AHaworth I do not manage to make more irregularities appear on each side of the image, as in the example url mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create any shape there is a css clip path generator.

Example web-site:

1. [cssportal.com](https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/).
2. [bennettfeely.com](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)
3. [uplabs.com](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/clip-path-generator)

Example code:

```css
img { 
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 80% 10%, 100% 35%, 100% 70%, 80% 90%, 50% 100%, 20% 90%, 0% 70%, 0% 35%, 20% 10%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 80% 10%, 100% 35%, 100% 70%, 80% 90%, 50% 100%, 20% 90%, 0% 70%, 0% 35%, 20% 10%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/d-wallpaper-textere-white-chamomiles-abstract-canvas-textures-d-wallpaper-textere-white-chamomiles-abstract-canvas-textures-160056709.jpg" alt="">
```

```css
div {
  background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/d-wallpaper-textere-white-chamomiles-abstract-canvas-textures-d-wallpaper-textere-white-chamomiles-abstract-canvas-textures-160056709.jpg");
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(23% 43%, 7% 31%, 5% 68%, 15% 85%, 51% 61%, 75% 83%, 86% 49%, 83% 19%, 60% 37%, 58% 19%, 45% 40%, 37% 28%);
clip-path: polygon(23% 43%, 7% 31%, 5% 68%, 15% 85%, 51% 61%, 75% 83%, 86% 49%, 83% 19%, 60% 37%, 58% 19%, 45% 40%, 37% 28%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
  background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/d-wallpaper-textere-white-chamomiles-abstract-canvas-textures-d-wallpaper-textere-white-chamomiles-abstract-canvas-textures-160056709.jpg");
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 44% 100%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 44% 100%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I found a better tool, even there is no curve on shapes: https://www.uplabs.com/posts/clip-path-generator

Answer (score 0):

I have used your clip path on an image and it seems fine.

My question though is whether you did indeed intend 'div' to be a class or were you actually trying to select a div element? (ie was there a misplaced dot?).

This snippet assumes you are wanting to select a div with an img in it:

```css
div img {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 16% 2%, 39% 0%, 83% 4%, 100% 0%, 100% 24%, 98% 48%, 100% 75%, 100% 100%, 75% 97%, 45% 100%, 1% 100%, 7% 81%, 0% 56%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300'>
</div>
```